# How to order a beer without garnish, simply?

Tags: garnish

Is there a simple word for ordering a beer sans garnish?  Say for instance I want a Hoegaarden...  It's a great beer in it's own right, and I don't want it to come decorated with a slice of orange that I have to take responsibility for disposing of.  How can I order the beer without it, quickly and easily?  I've tried "no decoration," but that sounds pretentious.  For a scotch, I would say "neat."  Is there a way to do that for beer?

Comment: I am from Belgium and I have never heard that people put a piece of fruit on a Hoegaarden beer. In Belgium, we never do that. I guess saying the beer without fruit or anything is fine :). Oh, and mention they shouldn't forget the glass, then it sounds funny :P.

Comment: I figured when writing this that Europeans wouldn't do something like that.  American's seem to want more flavor though...  Mais, ce n'est pas pour moi. ;)  Merci pour la réponse !

Comment: How kind of you to respond in French. However I do speak French and my name suggests I am French speaking, I am from the Dutch part of Belgium (Northern part) :).

Comment: +1  I hate it when they put a slice of lemon or lime in a [Negra Modelo](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/75/667/?ba=bros).  Might as well put lime in Guinness - Bleugh!  I usually specifically ask for NM "with no lemon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, I usually just ask for "no fruit" or "no orange/lime/garnish" and it has always seemed to work. Sometimes I will say "straight up" though I do still get the garnish on occasion I've come to find. I am not sure if this was because the bartender was busy and forgot or if there was some other reason, but I just tend to not say this as much anymore. I've never felt pretentious when I ask, I feel like I am just asking for a beer as is because I just happen to not want the garnish in it. Just be polite about ordering it and I am sure you won't come across as pretentious.

Comment: I try to say "no fruit" as well, and you're right, it's not super pretentious.  It's just not smooth, which is what I'm after.  Using "neat" for scotch is smooth and non-negative.  That's really what I'm going for...

Comment: I'm thinking that there really isn't a word for it, but you get props for saying what I would say...  Thanks!

Comment: A friend of mine always says "no salad" when ordering her corona. Maybe not as clear but definitely funny!